# python3 error: invalid mode %r" % mode, trying to use object in os.popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, subprocess, pickle

I am trying to access data from an object that has just been unpickled and use it with

```
os.popen()
```

hitting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmpclient4.py", line 46, in <module>
    stream = os.popen('%t.cmd', '%t.arg')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 978, in popen
    raise ValueError("invalid mode %r" % mode)
ValueError: invalid mode '%t.arg'
```

or error:

```
ValueError: invalid mode 'htop' #my object value
```

using

```
stream = os.popen('%t.cmd', '%t.arg')
```

or

```
stream = os.popen(t.cmd, t.arg)
```

code:

```
import socket
import pickle
import os

HEADERSIZE = 10

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.42.14', 666))

class Zeroquery:
        # Initializer / Instance Attributes
        def __init__(self, cmd, arg):
                self.cmd = cmd
                self.arg = arg
while True:
        full_msg = b''
        new_msg = True
        while True:
                msg = s.recv(16)
                if new_msg:
                        print("new msg len:",msg[:HEADERSIZE])
                        msglen = int(msg[:HEADERSIZE])
                        new_msg = False

                print(f"full message length: {msglen}")

                full_msg += msg


                print(len(full_msg))

                if len(full_msg)-HEADERSIZE == msglen:
                        print("full msg recvd")
                        t = pickle.loads(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:])
                        print(t.cmd, t.arg)
                        if t.cmd:
                                stream = os.popen(t.cmd, t.arg)
                                output = stream.read()
                                print(output)
                        new_msg = True
                        full_msg = b""
```

How do I use os.popen using my object data?

Comment: What is the value in ``t.arg``, it should be either ``r or w`` https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen

Comment: what is `'%t.cmd'`, `'%t.arg'` ? Maybe you need it as list, not separated arguments in popen - like `popen( [t.cmd, t.arg] )` ? Or as string `popen( "{} {}".format(t.cmd, t.arg) )` . Check documentation for popen.

Comment: @Sushanth  %t.cmd contains Zeroquery() object data from socket. It's value is 'echo'. In %t.arg, contains htop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create string with command and argument

```
cmd = "{} {}".format(t.cmd, t.arg)
```

or using f-string

```
cmd = f"{t.cmd} {t.arg}"
```

If `cmd` and `arg` are strings then you can do

```
cmd = " ".join([t.cmd, t.arg])
```

or

```
cmd = t.cmd + " " + t.arg
```

And now you can use it as first argument

```
os.popen(cmd)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Eventually you can create method `__str__` in `Zeroquery`

```
class Zeroquery:
    # Initializer / Instance Attributes
    def __init__(self, cmd, arg):
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.arg = arg

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cmd + " " + self.arg
```

and then you can use `str(t)`

```
os.popen( str(t) )
```

---

**BTW:**

When `Zeroquery` has `__str__` then you can print it (even without `str()`)

```
print( t )
```

and `print()` will use this `__str__` to convert to string.

Comment: I added example with `__str__`

Comment: missing an ' or ' between the join and concatenation examples.

Comment: @RufusVS both examples refer to condition `if cmd and arg are strings` so I decided skip `or` between them. I rather add `# or` in code.